# How to select an element by accessibility role and label in React Native Testing Library

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I have multiple buttons on my screen with different `accessibilityLabel`.

```html
<Button accessibilityLabel="First label">First</Button>
<Button accessibilityLabel="Second label">Second</Button>
```

Querying with `getByRole` ignores the second argument specifying the accessibility label (which works ok in non-native Testing Library).

```js
getByRole('button', { name: 'First label' })
```

How can I query an element by both a role and a label?